# Not chaining async functions?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

While attempting to recode an old system for a friend I'm having a few issues with async function calls with the **Jimp** node package: https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/tree/master/packages/jimp

Here's the code I've put together:

```
async format(file, config = {}) {

    try {

        return Jimp.read(file).then(image => {

             if (config.quality) {
                const quality = parseInt(config.quality.replace(/\D+/g, ''), 10);
                image.quality(quality);
            }

            if (config.brightness) {
                image.brightness(config.brightness);
            }

            return image.getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_JPEG);

        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }
}

let response = await this.format(file.Body, config);
```

That's a minimalist version of what I've put together, but I'm unsure on why the output buffer is 0kb? I'm thinking it's because I haven't done each function as a **Promise**?

Comment: Why are you using an `async` function if you're not using `await`?

Comment: @Dai question updated, sorry

Comment: `async` is a modifier for the function, not how it's used. You're still not using `await` inside the function.

Comment: @Dai I'm far from an expert in Node, any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `async` and `await` are not features of Node, they're built-in to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing an `async` function yet you're not using `await` - which defeats the point of using `async` to make Promises easier to work with.

Try this:

```
async format( file, config = {} ) {

    let image = await Jimp.read( file );
    if( config.quality ) {
        const quality = parseInt(config.quality.replace(/\D+/g, ''), 10);
        image.quality(quality);
    }

    if( config.brightness ) {
        image.brightness(config.brightness);
    }

    let buffer = await image.getBufferAsync( Jimp.MIME_JPEG );
    return buffer;
}
```

The `async` and `await` keywords in JavaScript behave essentially the same as their C# keywords (except operating on `Promise<T>` instead of `Task<T>`). The `await` keyword can only be used in functions with the `async` modifier (it also means that all `async` functions necessarily also return a `Promise<T>`).

So this:

```
async foo() { // returns Promise<T>

    let a = getA();

    let b = await getBAsync( a );

    let c = getC( b );

    let d = await getDAsync( c );
    return d;
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
foo() { // returns Promise<T>

    let a = getA();

    let bPromise = getBAsync( a );
    return bPromise.then( b => {

        let c = getC( b );

        let dPromise = getDAsync( c );
        return dPromise.then( d => {

            return d;
        } );

    } );
}
```

Or (using Promise chaining):

```
foo() { // returns Promise<T>

    let a = getA();

    return getBAsync( a )
        .then( b => {

            let c = getC( b );
            return c;
        } )
        .then( c => {

             return getDAsync( c );
        } );;
}
```

Tips:

- You should prefer using TypeScript to JavaScript in my opinion, as the correct use of `Promise<T>` is fraught with difficulties if you rely on JavaScript's weak typing.
- If you can't use TypeScript, you can still use `*.d.ts` files as a reference so you know which library functions you're using return `Promise<T>` (asynchronous functions) and which return `T` (synchronous, "normal" functions)

  - For example, Jimp's `d.ts` file is available here: https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/blob/master/packages/jimp/jimp.d.ts
- A common coding convention is to suffix function names with `Async` if it returns a `Promise<T>` as a courtesy to any library consumers of yours (though this is not universally common, e.g. ESLint decided against it: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8531 )

Comment: @Curtis I've amended my answer with more details and a comparison of `async` vs non-`async`.

Answer (score 0):

chain your async function properly with await like this

```
async format(file, config = {}) {

    try {

    const image = await Jimp.read(file);

    if (config.quality) {
                const quality = await parseInt(config.quality.replace(/\D+/g, ''), 10);
                await image.quality(quality);
        }

    if (config.brightness) {
                await image.brightness(config.brightness);
        }

    return await image.getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_JPEG);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }
}

let response = await this.format(file.Body, config);
```

Comment: According to Jimp's `jimp.d.ts` file (available here: https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/blob/master/packages/jimp/jimp.d.ts ), `Jimp.brightness` and `Jimp.quality` return `this`. They don't return `Promise<T>` so there is no reason to `await` those calls.

Comment: This code still doesn't run: `image` is undefined, `Jimp.read` returns a `Promise`, and `parseInt` isn't awaitable.